# Is there a way to change XCode 14 filelist's icons color scheme?

Tags: xcode4, vmware, macos-monterey

Recently I installed `XCode 14.2` and my files' icon's color changed to monochrome (grey-scale). When I use `XCode 13.x` on `macOS Big Sur` icons were colored (schemed).

I investigated all preferences options but no luck.

Is there a way to change it's scheme?

[image: You can see it from this SS]

I'm using `XCode 14.2` on `macOS Monterey 12.6.8` with-in `VMWare 16.2`